# Replace text with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When a user fills out a form and presses submit, the form is disabled while the information is submitted. I use the following code to disable the form:

```
$form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
```

How can I replace the text of the button with a loading image?

Comment: Please post your HTML code as well

Comment: check the link https://forum.jquery.com/topic/show-loading-image-when-clicking-a-link

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question, that one deals with mootools but this one deals with JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
$form.find('button').prop('disabled', true).html('<img src="yourimagesoruce">');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place "loading image" into the button, then as a solution you can set a "background-image" property to button with url of your "loading image". Also you can set additional properties to define how your image should look.

Example:

```
$form.find('button').prop('background-image', 'url("img/loading.gif")');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the button and add the background

```
$('input[type=submit]').css('background', "url('please_wait2.png') no-repeat top left");
```

and disable it

```
$('input[type=submit]').prop("disabled",true)
```

Comment: This css styling will show waiting image when button stat enable or disable, I'm I write or wrong?

Comment: When you submit the form, it will load the image as background image of button and then disables it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [**replaceWith**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_replacewith.asp) to replace the button

```
$(":submit").on("click", function (e) {
    $("form").prop("disabled", true);
    $(this).replaceWith("<img id='loadingImg' src='http://www.loadinfo.net/images/preview/11_cyrcle_one_24.gif?1384388177' />");    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btxKc/